# Windows Server 2008: add comment to a folder

Tags: windows-server-2008

is there a way to add comments to a folder in windows server 2008, maybe also through powershell?
In my company we have a shared server and I would like to give other users information about the meaning of some folders.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows *shares* can have comments specified when you create the share, however individual folders cannot. An easier solution might just be a read-me folder in each folder that requires a description.